# How to take objects as multiple arguments for django template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a two `lists`. Upon passing those two to a custom template tag, it should ZIP them and return the object.

Is it possible? If so how to do that?

The respective operation is :

```
def zip_tag(arg1, arg2):
    return zip(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Write in C? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S1fISh-pag

Comment: haha. I am not joking here.

Comment: When you say `return`, do you mean you want string representation of the result of the `zip`, or adding the result to context for future using?

Comment: How come you are doing this in a template and not the view?

Comment: I was thinking because of the name http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie

Comment: Actually, what I am building here.. should be a bit independent of python code.. So, was thinking to do something like this.

Comment: @okm The above code is just example.. I want to return the zip object not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joe says in the comments, I would consider zipping the lists in the view rather than the template. However, it should be possible to do it in the template with an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) (untested code):

```
@register.assignment_tag
def zip_tag(arg1, arg2):
    return zip(arg1, arg2)
```

You would use it in your template as follows:

```
{% zip_tag arg1 arg2 as zipped %}
<ul>
{% for x, y in zipped %}
  <li>x, y<li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```